# I want an error to pop up before user is asked to input something again

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In the code above, when I press any other key, I want an error message to pop up before returning the user_input. Please help someone?

Comment: A "print" statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if it's valid at the end of the `while` loop:

```
currencies = ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', '$', '£', '¥','€']

def get_currency(msg):
    while True:
        user_input = input(msg).lower()

        if user_input not in currencies:
            print('Invalid currency')
        else:
            return user_input
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
valid = ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', '$', '£', '¥','€']
msg="Enter currency: "
def get_currency(msg):

    input_valid = input(msg).lower()

    while input_valid not in valid:       #run this loop until the input is not valid
        print ("Invalid Input, Try again")  #the error message
        input_valid = input(msg).lower()

    return input_valid

print (get_currency(msg))
```

**output:**

```
~$ python3 so.py
Enter currency: foo
Invalid Input, Try again
Enter currency: bar
Invalid Input, Try again
Enter currency: pound
pound
```